# Windows 7 Swapping Threshold

Tags: memory, swap

When physical memory jumps to 80%, the RAM starts swapping itself to pagefile.
How to increase this 80% threshold to say 90% ?

I have 4GB of RAM which means the swapping starts when 3.2GB of RAM is utilized and 0.8GB is not in use.

Comment: Windows’ memory management system is not that simply. IIRC, it always swaps. This is different from Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Actually swaping doesn't work the way you are thinking you can increase your virtual memory but not the threshold to 90% for swaping.

see this answer for more details.

[Should I disable swap file if I have lots of RAM or should I move it to a virtual RAM drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/810170/should-i-disable-swap-file-if-i-have-lots-of-ram-or-should-i-move-it-to-a-virtua)